Ideals of functions whose zero locus is a submanifold
Let $M$ be a smooth $m$ dimensional manifold. Suppose that $f_1,\dots,f_k\in C^\infty(M)$ are smooth functions such that the zero locus $$N:=Z_f=\lbrace p\in M:\ f_i(p)=0,\ \forall i=1,2,\dots,k\rbrace$$ is a submanifold.
Then we have a pair of ideals $$\mathcal I_N = \lbrace f\in C^\infty(M):\ f(p)=0\ p\in N\rbrace$$ and $$ \mathcal I_f =\langle f_1,\dots,f_k\rangle, $$i.e. the former is the ideal of functions vanishing on $N$, and the latter is the ideal generated by the functions $f_1,\dots,f_k$. Obviously $\mathcal I_f\subseteq\mathcal I_N$.
Let's say that the system of functions $f=(f_1,\dots,f_k)$ has rank $r\le k$ at $p\in N$ if the system of 1-forms $\mathrm{d}f_1(p),\dots,\mathrm{d}f_k(p)$ has rank $r$. Then the system $f$ has constant rank if the rank is the same for all points of $N$ (we only require this for points on $N$).
It is clear that if the system $f$ has constant rank $r = \mathrm{codim}(N)$ (which includes the special, very regular case $r=k$), then the two ideals coincide $\mathcal I_N=\mathcal I_f$. But generally this is not the case.
I assume that if the system $f$ does not have constant rank then the problem gets a bit untractable, so we may assume that $f$ has constant rank.
The question is whether there is any general relation between the ideals $\mathcal{I}_N$ and $\mathcal I_f$? And by that I mean any general relation that can be formulated in any terms that can be reasonably considered "useful". As in $\mathcal I_f\subseteq\mathcal I_N$ is a "general relation", but it is way too generic to give any meaningful information. I realize this is somewhat subjective, though.
A typical example is when $g$ is a single function whose differential does not vanish at $N$, then the "system" $f=g^2$ generates the same submanifold, but is rank $0$. The ideals do not coincide since $\mathcal I_N$ contains $g$, but $\mathcal I_f$ does not. This makes me think that radical ideals are involved, but I do not expect this particularly simple case to be anywhere close to generic.

Are you looking for something like the real Nullstellensatz  for general manifolds instead of just $\mathbb R^n$ ?

@Overflowian Iirc the real Nullstellensatz still deals with polynomials. What I am looking for is something analogous but with arbitrary smooth functions, with the caveat that the zero sets must be manifolds (otherwise I imagine its pretty wild west out there, every closed set is essentially a zero locus). The global aspects actually don't interest me that much, relations characterizing germs would be sufficient for me. For example one relation would be how to obtain "nondegenerate" generators from "degenerate" ones, etc.

If $M$ is compact, then $\mathcal I_N$ is the intersection of the maximal ideals containing $\mathcal I_f$ (the Nullstellensatz tells you the same thing with prime ideals). This has nothing to do with smoothness for the functions or the zero locus, it is true for every ring of continuous functions over a compact space where functions with no zeros are invertible.

If $M$ is not compact, then it will is likely to depend on the behaviour of $f$ at infinity: over $\mathbb R$, taking $f=(x^2-1)/(1+x^2)$ will give you a different ideal than simply taking $f=x^2-1$. In the first case we have the relation of my previous comment, but not in the second.

@PierrePC can you give us some reference please?

@Overflowian I think this is done by hand fairly easily. In a ring of functions $R$, ideals $\mathfrak m_x:={f:f(x)=0}$ are clearly maximal (or the full ring). If $I$ is any ideal, then either there exists $f_x\in I$ with $f_x(x)\neq0$ for all $x$ and then over a compact base some finite combination $f_{x_1}^2+\cdots+f_{x_n}^2$ will be a non vanishing element of $I$, or $I\subset\mathfrak m_x$ for some $x$. This gives you all maximal ideals of $R$ if non-vanishing elements are invertible, and my first claim follows.

@Overflowian The same thing will happen if $f$ is $x\mapsto(x^2-1)/(1+x^2)$: a maximal ideal containing $f$ must be prime, hence contain either $1+x^2$, $x-1$ or $x+1$. The first case is not possible, the second and third means that the ideal contains respectively $\mathfrak m_1$ or $\mathfrak m_{-1}$.

@Overflowian Aaand... I realize now I was wrong and you probably saw it. The same thing will happen with x↦x2−1, obviously, so it is not a counterexample to what I tought. In fact based on this question I am fairly certain $\mathcal I_N$ is always the intersection of the maximal ideals containing $\mathcal I_f$, which again has little to do with smoothness.

Let $R\subset\mathbb R^M$ be an $\mathbb R$-algebra of functions over some set $M$ (i.e. a ring that contains the constants). Suppose also that every $f\in R$ that vanishes nowhere is invertible. I will show that if $I$ is finitely generated and $J$ is the ideal of functions that vanish over the common zero set of the elements of $I$, then $J$ is in fact the intersection of the maximal ideals containing $I$. In my notations, we will have $\mathcal I_f=I=\langle f_1,\ldots,f_k\rangle$ and $\mathcal I_N=J(Z_Z(I))$.
This is in the spirit of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, which tells you that of $I$ is an ideal of $k[X_1,\ldots,X_\ell]$ ($k$ a field, so the ideal must be finitely generated) and $J$ is the ideal of polynomials that vanish over the common zero set of the elements of $I$ over the algebraic closure of $k$, then $J$ is the intersection of the prime ideals containing $I$. Our case is not as interesting in a sense, since the latter intersection is the radical $\sqrt I$ of $I$ and it is easy to detect whether $f\in\sqrt I$. I am not aware of such an easy criterion for the intersection of maximal ideals, but the keyword of Jacobson radical may help. In general $J$ is the set of $f\in R$ such that for all $g\in R$, $I+\langle\mathbf1+fg\rangle=R$, which is not extremely transparent in your application.
The proof is highly inspired by paragraph IV-3.3 in Johnstone's Stone Spaces, which was brought to my attention by this question.
Stone zero sets. For $I$ an ideal of $R$, let $Z_S(I)$ (the S of Stone) be the set of all the zero sets of $g\in I$; it is stable under finite intersections (consider $g_1^2+g_2^2+\cdots+g_k^2$) and upward closed within the collection of all zero sets of elements of $R$ (consider $fg$). In other words, it is a (possibly degenerate) filter within the lattice of zero sets of elements of $R$. For $F$ such a filter, let $J(F)$ be the collection of functions $f\in R$ whose zero set is in $F$. This is an ideal because $F$ is a lattice (the zero set of $f_1g_1+f_2g_2$ is a superset of the intersection of the zero sets of $f_1$ and $f_2$). It should be clear that $I\subset J(Z_S(I))$, and $J(Z_S(I))\subset J(Z_S(I'))$ whenever $I\subset I'$.
Suppose that $I$ is not $R$ itself. Then $\varnothing\notin Z_S(I)$ since functions vanishing nowhere are invertible, and $\mathbf1\notin J(Z_S(I))$. In particular, for a maximal ideal $\mathfrak m\subset R$, we must have $\mathfrak m\subset J(Z_S(\mathfrak m))\subsetneq R$, hence $\mathfrak m=J(Z_S(\mathfrak m))$. This means that for every ideals $I\subset\mathfrak m$ with $\mathfrak m$ maximal, $J(Z_S(I))\subset J(Z_S(\mathfrak m))=\mathfrak m$, and $J(Z_S(I))$ is included in the intersection of the maximal ideals containing $I$.
Zariski zero sets. For $I$ an ideal of $R$, let $Z_Z(I)$ (the Z of Zariski) be the set of all the zero sets of $g\in R$ that contain the common zero set of all elements of $I$; it is stable under finite (even arbitrary) intersections and upward closed within the collection of all zero sets of elements of $R$, so it is also a filter. It does not have to be a principal filter, since it may be that the intersection of all zero sets of the elements of $I$ is not a zero set itself,¹ but it comes close.
Fix an ideal $I$ and write $N$ for the intersection of all the zero sets of elements in $I$. We want to show that for $g$ in the intersection of all maximal ideals containing $I$, $g$ vanishes over $N$. For $x\in M$, write $\mathfrak m_x$ for the ideal of functions that vanish at $x$; it is maximal since it is the kernel of the evaluation map $R\to\mathbb R$ at $x$ and $\mathbb R$ is a field. If $x\in N$, then $f(x)=0$ for all $f\in I$, and $I\subset\mathfrak m_x$ so $g\in\mathfrak m_x$ and $g(x)=0$; this concludes.
Conclusion. We have showed that for any ideal $I\subset R$,
$$ J(Z_S(I))\subset\bigcup_{\mathfrak m\supset I\text{ maximal}}\mathfrak m\subset J(Z_Z(I)). $$
If $Z_S(I)$ is principal (i.e. it consists of all zero sets that contains some specific $\{f=0\}$ for some $f\in R$), then let us show that $Z_S(I)=Z_Z(S)$. This would conclude since $Z_Z(I)$ is principal when $I$ is finitely generated (consider $f_1^2+\cdots+f_k^2$), and even if $R$ is the ring of all smooth functions over a manifold and $I$ is countably generated (consider $\sum\varepsilon_kf_k^2$ for $\varepsilon_k\to0$ fast enough).
Suppose that $Z_S(I)$ is principal, so it has a smallest element $\{f=0\}$ with $f\in I$. Obviously, this set must be the intersection of all zero sets of all elements of $I$, and $Z_Z(I)$ is the set of functions that vanish over $\{f=0\}$. Now $g\in Z_Z(I)$ if and only if $\{g=0\}$ contains $\{f=0\}$ if and only if $g\in Z_S(I)$, and the proof is complete.
¹ For instance, consider $R$ the algebra of functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ that are locally constant on a neighborhood of zero (that may vary depending on the function) and $I$ the collection of functions that vanish at zero.

Here is also a direct proof that $g\in\mathcal I_N=:J$ if and only if $1+gh$ is invertible in $\mathcal C^\infty(M,\mathbb R)/\mathcal I_f=:R/I$ for all $h\in R$. (=>) If $g\in J,h\in R$ then $(1+gh)^2+f_1^2+\cdots+f_k^2$ has an inverse $r$, and $(1+gh+I)((1+gh)r+I)=1-f_1^2r-\cdots-f_k^2r+I=1+I$. (<=) If $g\notin J$ then for some $x\in M$ we have $g(x)\neq0$; choose $h\equiv-1/g(x)$. If $(1+gh+I)(r+I)=1+I$, then $1+\mathfrak m_x=(1+gh)r+\mathfrak m_x\simeq(1+gh)(x)r(x)=0$, a contradiction. The proof works whenever $N$ is the zero set of a single element of $I$ (i.e. $Z_Z(I)=Z_S(I)$).
